# ASP.NET Core app won't start in container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET Core app which I'm trying to deploy in a docker container. I have a different container for development, which works fine, but I can't get a production version to work.

The dockerfile (see below) I have is based on the one from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/), the application builds just fine, but won't run. I get the following error:

```
web_1  |   It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
web_1  |   Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
web_1  |       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

After which the container terminates with code 145.

Dockerfile.prod:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs unzip libc6-dev libgdiplus

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
ADD . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
RUN mkdir -p /openld-data/fixture-images
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "openld.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - openld-data:/openld-data
  db:
    image: "postgres:12.1"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB:
        POSTGRES_USER:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres-data:
  openld-data:
```

I don't know why it isn't working, the sample ASP.NET containers do something very similar and work just fine. If anyone knows what causes this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be this line:

```
 volumes:
  - ./:/app
```

It maps your local current drive to containers `/app`. So instead the executable you've built in container, you're using the one built on your machine.
Delete the `- ./:/app` and give it a try.